# How to get a device's supported interrupt modes in C (Windows)?

Tags: c, interrupt

I'm trying to create an application that can change the interrupt modes on graphics cards. I figured out how to get the device instance path in code and change if msi mode should be on or off, but I can't figure out how to query windows on if msi mode is supported. Does anyone know how to? It is possible since MSI mode utility tells you.

I tried searching for an answer for my problem but I had no luck. In device manager I did find a value that may be useful under the details tab on my graphics card. The value is called `PCI interrupt support` but its just a number and I have no way of reading. Searching it also gave no useful results.

Answer (score 1):

I hope I understand the question correctly since this is not exactly my field but after some googling I found out there should be an `MSISupported` REG_DWORD value in the [MSI api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/kernel/enabling-message-signaled-interrupts-in-the-registry) which is described as:

> The MSISupported entry of Interrupt Management\MessageSignaledInterruptProperties is a REG_DWORD value that determines whether the device supports MSIs. Set MSISupported to 1 to enable MSI support.

I guess you can then just send some message from win side which tells the device side to answer you whether it supports MSI or not.

Comment: I read the same article but I believe that the `MSISupported` Dword just sets if msi mode is on or off according to https://forums.guru3d.com/threads/windows-line-based-vs-message-signaled-based-interrupts-msi-tool.378044/. Thanks for the info though!